# Saving a screenshot from selenium to absolute path

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently trying to write a script (to plug in to a Django project) to take a screenshot of a full page of a website using Selenium.

Everything seems to be running OK - the path (fullimsavepath) builds OK (hence the print statement to output so I can see), selenium doesn't report any errors, and the script exits fine. However,

when I look for the actual screenshot in the path provided, it doesn't exist there. What am I doing wrong? Is it something to do with relative vs. absolute paths?

Running Python 3.8 on Windows inside pipenv.

Code:

```
import time
import os
from sitehawk.settings import BASE_DIR
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from datetime import datetime, date


def takescreenshot(url='http://www.google.com', filename='testpng1'):

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True
    # Need to replace executable path with environment variable or similar for production?
    # At the moment it's an absolute path to the driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=r'C:/Users/gapbr/Documents/dev/sitehawk/sitehawk-project/screenshots/driver/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)

    # Set the path where the image should be saved
    actualdate = datetime.now()
    yr = actualdate.strftime('%Y')
    mn = actualdate.strftime('%m')
    filepng = filename+'.png'
    fullimsavepath = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'screenshots','captured-files',yr,mn,filepng)
    print(fullimsavepath)

    # Take the screenshot
    S = lambda X: driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scroll'+X)
    driver.set_window_size(S('Width'),S('Height')) # May need manual adjustment
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').screenshot(fullimsavepath)

    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you try specifying the path manually?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Python have doubling of literals like Java does. Try to double your slashes in path like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=r'C://Users/gapbr//Documents//dev//sitehawk//sitehawk-project//screenshots//driver//chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: The problem isn't loading the driver, that's working fine, but actually saving the file!

Answer (score 0):

I have very little knowledge of python. But, for your reference, I have used the below code in my C# project to take a screenshot. I hope you get some ideas from this:

```
static public void getCapture(string No = "1")
    {
        //Screenshot
        Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)Tests.driver).GetScreenshot();
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        //Saving_the_screenshot_with_a_filename
        var title = dt.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm") + "_" + No + ".png";
        string file = System.IO.Path.Combine(appSettings.Settings["ScreenShotPath"].Value);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
        {
            file = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        }
        ss.SaveAsFile(file + @"\" + title);
    }
```